# Insert data with MAX(id) and values of status at the same time

Tags: php, html, sql, database, mysqli

I was trying with this code but it didn't work. it's always get the `MAX(eq_no)` as `0`

```
    $sql1 =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(eq_no) AS val FROM tech_add_equip");

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO time (eq_no,status_no) VALUES ('$val', 4 );";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2)) { 
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); };
```

Finally, after I try with this code, it inserts in the right number of `MAX(eq_no)` but i still cant insert the values of `status_no`

```
INSERT INTO time (eq_no) SELECT MAX(eq_no) AS vale FROM tech_add_equip
```

Could you suggest me what did i missing in the code?

Thank you for your helping

Comment: Your code should return an error.  What are you trying to do and why are you not using `auto_increment`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT instead MAX(eq_no)? did you mean like this? i want the last_insert_id of eq_no to insert to another table

Comment: . . Your question makes no reference to inserting into multiple tables.  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask a more appropriate question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  i want to insert 2 values in 1 table but before i insert i have to select the LAST_INSERT_ID first. Is this clear for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One row returned from `SELECT a,b,c` statement in sub query is equivalent to set of values that is otherwise hardcoded as `('a-value','b-value','c-value')`*. You can hardcode a value within select as well:

```
INSERT INTO time (eq_no, status_no)
    SELECT MAX(eq_no), 4
    FROM tech_add_equip
```

No need for aliases within select - order of columns matters.

---

*) One row result can be used for `IN()` clause. Another row would become set of values after comma - can't be uset for `IN()`, but it works ok for `INSERT`

```
('row1-a-value', 'row1-b-value'), ('row2-a-value', 'row2-b-value')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = SELECT MAX( customer_id ) FROM customers;
       INSERT INTO customers( customer_id, statusno )
       VALUES ($max , 4)
```

Comment: Sorry this is not work too. it cant get value of customer_id to insert to customers